# How to create a dataframe column from values with frequency count?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a problem set, with values and their associated frequencies, how can the `sample` be created in a dataframe?

```
Find the mean of this dataset
Value: 1 | 2 | 3
Freq:  3 | 4 | 2
```

Which represents the `sample`, `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]`.

I input this into Python:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1, 2, 3], 'freq':[4, 5, 2]})
>>> df
   value  freq
0      1     3
1      2     4
2      3     2
```

It's not difficult to find solve basic statistics with this format. For example, the mean for this dataset is `(df['value'] * df['freq']).sum() / df['freq'].sum()`. However it would be nice to use built in functions/attributes such as `.mean()`. To do this I need to input the value/freq data as raw value data into the data frame. My end goal is this:

```
    data
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
6      2
7      3
8      3
```

Does anybody know how to input datasets given in value/frequency form and create a data frame of raw data? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is to use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
import numpy as np

values = [1,2,3]

frequency = [3,4,2]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(values, frequency), columns=['data'])

df.mean()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use tuple or list multiplication:

```
# Duplicate the value `freq` times.
values = [(value,)*freq for (value, freq) in zip(df["value"], df["freq"])]
>>> [(1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3)]

# Flatten the list of tuples into a list of values.
values = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist]
>>> [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]

mean = np.mean(values)
```

Interestingly, I cannot do `df["data"] = values` for some reason. It causes this error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['freq'])]
df['value'].mean()
```

Comment: This is a good solution! I would recommend also adding the line `df = df.drop(columns = ['freq'])` to remove the frequency column left behind. You can also rename 'values' to 'data' with `df = df.rename({'value':'data'})`. This helps signify that the data frame is not a list of values that's missing a frequency column, rather this is the raw data.